# Have an issue with the css :nth-child property

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an issue with the property `:nth-child`, i'm trying to modify a div child property when this div is in hover position but it didn't work well and nothing happened, do someone have the solution ?

Here is my code :

```css
.army_selection:hover::nth-child(1) {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.army_selection_bloc {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: aqua;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="army1" class="army_selection">
  <div class="army_selection_bloc">
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of issues...

1. There should only be one
   colon before `nth-child`. The double colon syntax is used for pseudo *elements* (eg. `::before`, `::after`) rather then pseudo *selectors*.
2. There should be a space before `:nth-child`. You want to select a child element, not the element itself.
3. `visibility` is a non-animatable property and so can not be transitioned. You could use
   `opacity` instead.

```css
.army_selection:hover :nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.army_selection_bloc {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: aqua;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="army1" class="army_selection">
  <div class="army_selection_bloc">
   
  </div>
</div>
```

This may not be the effect you are looking for, but if you move the transition from the hover state to the default state, the element will fade in and out.

```css
.army_selection:hover :nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 1;
}

.army_selection_bloc {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: aqua;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="army1" class="army_selection">
  <div class="army_selection_bloc">
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.army_selection:hover div:nth-child(1) {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.army_selection_bloc {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: aqua;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#army1{
background-color:yellow;
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="army1" class="army_selection">
  <div class="army_selection_bloc">
   First DIv
  </div>
</div>
```

Check the above code. You need to select the nth-child of div inside `.army-selection`

Answer (score -3):

this will work check below demo

```css
.army_selection:hover .army_selection_bloc:nth-child(1) {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.army_selection{
background-color:red;
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:relative;
}

.army_selection_bloc {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: aqua;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="army1" class="army_selection">
i am a parent div
  <div class="army_selection_bloc">
   i am a child div
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem is this is:

```
.army_selection:hover::nth-child(1) {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

should be like this

```
.army_selection:hover .army_selection_bloc:nth-child(1) {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

the nth-child property must need a class to identify the child element anyone finds wrong correct me.

Comment: Try? This is an answer section, not guesswork section.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović i am new didn't know about this rule but fixed

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. You should *explain* what you changed and why it should solve the problem.

Comment: @Quentin i just wanted to fast reply to gain reputation thats why i just put fast but next time i will keep in mind these things thank you both